# libgdx: how to hide startup screen

Tags: android, screen, hide, libgdx, startup

I am working on libgdx program with 2 screens named "Show Info.". A 'startup' screen always popup first. How could I hide it?

[image: screen dump for libgdx 'startup' screen]

Thank you very much!

Regards,
Antony

Answer (score 1):

You are using Screen and Game classes?

```
@Override
public void create() {
    mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen(this);
    anotherScreen = new AnotherScreen(this);
    setScreen(mainMenuScreen);              
}
```

Make sure you call the `setScreen` method.

I'm a little unclear on what you are asking, could you elaborate a little more? What is this 'startup' screen you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` instead of `Activity` .. The `Service` can be working in the background without a UI.

Example to use the service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
//TODO do something useful
return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
//TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try.  And answer to badcc: Yes, I use Screen and Game classes. I just change the 2 tutorial with 2 screen as my program.  Thank you both of you.